# android ImageButton in scrollview with some effects while scrolling to the position

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I am thinking to implement the following function.

Five ImageButtons have been added into the scrollview.

Let's say if I set the scrollview can display 3 ImagesButton(1,2,3) in the view.

How can I set the effect for the middle button(2)(maybe something like the middle button is brighter than others)?

The position is fixed. So when I scroll up and down in the view, the middle button will be always brighter than others.

If any of you know how to implement it. Please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

: )

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Please allow me to elaborate my question. For example, Gallery makes the special effect(spot light?) on the Image that in the specified position. My intention is to make this effect on the ImageButtons rely in the scrollview. I took scrollview instead of using Gallery because I want to list these images vertically. I know it is more complicated to do it using if I took Gallery.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you could just dynamically set the background of the button to a unique layout file whenever your case arises.